# How do I work around html input inherited font sizing problem?

Tags: html, css

This feels like a chrome bug to me, but I thought I'd ask the community in case there's a workaround.

If I create an HTML input with the style `font: inherit` and a web font, the input size is incorrect until it's hovered.

**Before:**

[image: Before hover]

**After mouse hover:**

[image: After hover]

This size change can be particularly annoying if the input is in a flow layout and the size change causes elements to change position.

My code:
https://jsfiddle.net/nbilyk/sayfekc2/14/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@200;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    html {
      font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
      font-size: 24;
    }
    
    input {
      font: inherit;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="datetime-local">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked perfected on my Windows Chrome (Version 73.0.3683.86)

Comment: I am trying replicate the problem with the jsfiddle example but all works fine. Tried with Brave and Chrome.

Comment: Strange..  I'm on Win 10, Chrome 83 and if I can reproduce it every time by hard refreshing the page.

Comment: I can reproduce it, both on Chrome 83 and 86 (Canary). Definitely a Chrome bug,

Comment: Not on other Chromium based browsers though. Tried Edge, Brave, Opera and Iridium, all fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate to format this exactly, the best way is to set the textbox's display style to none and write a div tag with a key press event handler to mimic the textbox which displays the input in the div tag and adds the div tag's contents to the hidden textbox's value.
This is a lot of work for such a small problem but it means you have complete control over the style.
If you actually choose this path make a comment and I'll be happy to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Hehe, no, not that desperate. If I need to I can set the width explicitly. I submitted a bug through Chrome's help menu :)

Comment: How did you eventually resolve this, please @Nick Bilyk ?